# For each as Key with AND

Tags: php

I have one textbox and select form which is generated by the loop. It is Name and Discount.

I got problem in inserting them into database. Here is my code.

I dunno how to fix the foreach. If I create another foreach it doubles the input.

```
      foreach($_POST['name'] as $key)
      foreach($_POST['discount'] as $disccc)
```

Kindly help me thank you.

```
        foreach($_POST['name'] as $key AND $_POST['discount'] as $disccc)
        {

        if(is_numeric($key))
        {
        $error_msg .= "<img src='img/warning.png' style='height:60px;width:60px;'></img><strong style='color:yellow;'>Name must not contain numeric characters.</strong><br><br>";
        $flag = 1;
        }
        if(empty($key))
        {
        $error_msg .= "<img src='img/warning.png' style='height:60px;width:60px;'></img><strong style='color:yellow;'>Please fill in all the fields.</strong><br><br>";
        $flag = 1;
        }



        if($flag == 0)
        {
                $pass = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_passenger 
                VALUES
                (
                NULL, 
                '".$id."',
                '".$key."', 
                '".$disccc."', 
                '1'
                )
                ")or die(mysql_error());                    
                }



                $audit_trail = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_audit_trail
                VALUES(
                NULL,
                '".$_SESSION['user']."',
                NOW(),
                '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                'Made a reservation'
                )
                ")or die(mysql_error());    

                if($first_insert && $pass && $audit_trail)
                {
                $result = "reserve_success";
                echo ("<script language='Javascript'>
                window.location.href='regular_payment.php?reference=$id';
                </script>");
                }

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only iterate over a single array with a `foreach` loop.  You *could* make use of [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) but it sounds like a bad design choice anyway if your data is coming straight from `$_POST` as you can't guarantee arrays of the same length.  Subject to error handling though, it would look similar to...

```php
foreach(array_combine($arr1, $arr2) as $key => $val)
    echo "$key => $val \n"; // ...
```

[**» example**](http://ideone.com/zE92pm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$name) {
   if(is_numeric($name)){
        $error_msg .= "<img src='img/warning.png' style='height:60px;width:60px;'></img><strong style='color:yellow;'>Name must not contain numeric characters.</strong><br><br>";
   } elseif(empty($name)) {
        $error_msg .= "<img src='img/warning.png' style='height:60px;width:60px;'></img><strong style='color:yellow;'>Please fill in all the fields.</strong><br><br>";
   } else {
        $product = $_POST['discount'][$key];
        $pass = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_passenger VALUES( NULL, '".$id."', '".$name."',  '".$product."',  '1' ) ")or die(mysql_error()); 
   }

}
```